# Solving Homogeneous system of equations with an inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

First the exercise asked to find the inverse matrix of the following matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 3\\
0 & 2 & 1\\
-1 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$$

I found out that:
$$
A^{-1}=0.5\begin{pmatrix}-4 & 0 & -6\\
-1 & 1 & -1\\
2 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Later they asked to solve the following equations while using that last exercise:
$$
\begin{cases}
x+3z=1\\
2y+z=2\\
-x-2z=-3
\end{cases}
$$
I don't understand how should I use the inverse matrix to solve this equation. I see that $A$ is exactly the Homogeneous system of equations. But how does it help us?
As I understand they want me to solve this system of equations without exactly solving the matrix again.

Comment: Did you mean $x+3\color{red}z=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ -3\end{pmatrix}$,
then $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ -3\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: The answer is $\begin{pmatrix}x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}7\\
2\\
-2
\end{pmatrix}$ but the answer of the system equations is actually, $(x,y,z)=(\frac{1}{7},\frac{2}{7},\frac{10}{7})$. What am I missing?

Comment: is it $x+3z=1$ or $x+3y=1$?

Comment: It is:  $x+3z=1$. Nevermind, thanks :)

Comment: $(7,2,-2)$ is the solution for $x+3z=1$; in the question you had originally typed $x+3y=1$, and $(\frac17,\frac27,\frac{10}7)$ is the solution to that system

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your system of equations as $$A*U=b$$

where $U=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}T$ and $b=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2 \\ -3\end{pmatrix}$, $A$ is your matrix.

You know the inverse of $A$. You can write then
$$U=A^{-1}b$$

Finally,$$$$

$$U=0.5\begin{pmatrix}-4 & 0 & -6\\
-1 & 1 & -1\\
2 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2 \\ -3\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: why $b=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ -2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$? should not it be  $b=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2 \\ -3\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: because I need glasses ...thank you